# C# clearing key buffer

Tags: c#

I have a console game where the player selects and ability by pressing a number, the ability is done to the enemy, we wait 2 seconds then the enemy does his ability to the player, then we wait 2 seconds again and we start over. I find that if the player presses a key for an ability while this waiting is going on on the next loop it'll do it right away (the key press is sitting in the buffer). I want to clear that buffer at the start of each loop.

I tried the following but it never comes back from the Peek() call.

```
private void FlushKeyboard()
{
   while (Console.In.Peek() != -1)
        Console.In.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Console.KeyAvailable` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.keyavailable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see if there are keys to be read and then use ReadKey to read it:

```
while (Console.KeyAvailable)
{
    ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Also, if you don't want the typed characters to show on screen, you can use the override that accepts an [intercept flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
```